# What are the risks of leaving Namibia for a short "visa break"?

Tags: visas, namibia

A traveller has been advised to leave Namibia for South Africa for a fortnight, and to obtain a new visa on arrival return to Namibia, in order to extend their stay in the country.

They would prefer to remain in Namibia longer, but although they have been able to obtain a visa extension once already, the second request for extension has been declined.

The traveller has been in Namibia since December, has a return air ticket ticket from Namibia to Europe and can prove a date of return.

What are the risks of attempting to do this? Are visa breaks of this kind known to be successful as a way of extending a stay in Namibia?

Comment: Imagine yourself as Namibia Immigration. Would your records system retain the record of a declined extension request? Would you think the traveler was staying longer in Namibia that was previous allowed? Would this suggest special scrutiny or outright denial or further sanctions? To me, all those questions are likely answered "yes."

Comment: A return flight ticket is not really proof of anything as regards intention to leave, since it can often be changed or even abandoned altogether in favour of a new booking.

Comment: I think it's a really bad idea to risk it without being very confident of success. I've advised the traveller to get official advice (i.e. from Home Affairs and Immigration) before trying anything of the sort.